# Why is my variable setting itself to " when trying to set to another variable containing a string?

Tags: python-2.7

**In Theory:** When `game_start` is called and the user inputs `'easy'` the variable `quiz_paragraph` should assume the value of `easy_paragprah`

**In Actuality:** The value of `quiz_paragraph` is set to `"`

I can verify that `user_difficulty` is being set properly and is feeding `'easy'` properly into `set_difficulty`. The `if` statement runs but doesn't alter the value of `quiz_paragraph`.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing here?

```
# Easy Paragraph
easy_paragraph = '''\n___1___ is a programming ___2___ used to solve simple and complex problems. ___1___ like 
many languages can be used to display a message to a user using ___3___. Try it sometime. 
To display this common message by typing ___3___ '___4___ World!' \n'''

# Init Variables
user_difficulty = ""
quiz_paragraph = ""

# Ask user difficulty
def ask_difficulty():
    user_difficulty = raw_input("What difficulty level would you like? ")
    return user_difficulty

# Difficulty sets returned Paragraph 
def set_difficulty(difficulty):
    if difficulty == "easy":
        quiz_paragraph = easy_paragraph
        return quiz_paragraph
    else:
        print '''Sorry, that is not a valid choice.'''

# Start the game
def game_start():
    set_difficulty(ask_difficulty())
    print quiz_paragraph

# Game Start Test
game_start()
```

Comment: Why is it people downvote questions with zero reasons given? You would think they would want us to learn what we did wrong?

Comment: Not your down-voter, but 1) get rid of the apologies paragraph as it adds no information that would be helpful to future visitors with similar problems or to folks who might answer your question. 2) your question could be improved by showing the concrete results obtained from your searches of similar questions on this and other sites. I'm not talking about throw away lines such as "I searched everywhere and found nothing" but again ***concrete*** results. This site expects that you will do an exhaustive search *prior* to asking, and has high standards.

Comment: Also no one is required to comment when posting up-votes or down-votes as that often leads to little but flame wars. Check the [meta site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261173/how-do-we-avoid-downvotes-without-a-comment) for more discussions on this topic as it gets asked a lot

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have an issue with scope.

The `quiz_paragraph` variable within `set_difficulty`, is not the same as the 'global' `quiz_paragraph`.  Although they currently share the same name, you could rename the one inside `set_difficulty` to `foo` and you would have the same result.

You need to set the 'global' `quiz_paragraph` to the value returned by `set_difficulty`, or a better another local variable within `game_start`.  That is,

```
def game_start():
    quiz_paragraph = set_difficulty(ask_difficulty())
    print quiz_paragraph
```

or

```
def game_start():
    my_difficulty = set_difficulty(ask_difficulty())
    print my_difficulty
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize that Global/Local was a factor. Just as a quick question to make sure I understand. So a variable that is more than a single "level" deep in a function becomes a local variable? So if I want to change a global variable I have to do it in the first "tier" of a function/loop/etc.

Comment: Correct.  Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/292502/1290118 for a quick run-down of the rules.

Comment: Thank you again. Appreciate you helping out the noob. Reading up on it now.